# Grouped figure, connect points in group when x values are missing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have below code

```
ggplot(page, aes(x = factor(AVISITN), y = mean, colour = factor(TRT, labels = trt_labels))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(group=1, aes(x=factor(AVISITN), y = mean)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lowersd, ymax = uppersd), width = 0) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "green"), name="") +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2, ncol=1)) +
  labs(x = "Visit", y = "Mean and +/- SD") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 7)) +
  scale_x_discrete(guide=guide_axis(angle=-45))
```

Which is producing a grouped plot. But for one TRT group lines are not connected in several places - see example with pink line on the plot below. This is because this TRT group data is missing for x values (180-210).
I want to displays data for these two groups for the same x values so I want this line to be visible.
How to achieve this?

I will be glad.

[image]

Comment: Presumably you don't want to risk implying you have that data - do you want to impute the values somehow, or literally just link the two halves with a straight line (maybe a dashed one to reinforce its different nature)?

Comment: I don't want to impute any additional values - just want to display this pink line but I want this line to be included in the group so it should be green. I only wanted to highlight it with different color on this post purpose

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.